# Why is this migration corrupt? laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, migration

[image]

it fails when I try to refresh it when I delete the tables by hand and run php artisan migrate it works.

this is my migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('file');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('albumid')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('albumid')->references('id')->on('album');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('images');
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to run `composer dumpautoload`, and make sure your class name is correct (not shown in your code)

Comment: please add the whole code within file with filename

Comment: added the whole code now

Comment: running dump autoload fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it running

```
composer dump-autoload
```